# change tls fingerprint nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I need some help in changing the tls fingerprint in nodejs. Certain API's that apply tls fingerprinting are detecting that my requests are coming from a nodejs application (node-fetch or axios or any other http library). In other languages such as go or python its easy to change the ciphersuites to mimic a fingerprint of a modern browser but it seems like its impossible in nodejs.

Does anyone maybe have an idea how to do it? You can send a GET request to https://ja3er.com/json to check the tls fingerprint. For nodejs its always c4aac137ff0b0ac82f3c138cf174b427.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/tls-fingerprinting-node-js/